# Can you use different icon images for each list element within an unordered list?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm not an advanced user of CSS, but I have a decent working knowledge i suppose. I'm tryin to make an unordered list that uses different icons for each list element. I would also like the background colour of the list element to change upon hover.

Is there a way to do this through CSS, or would you just include the icon image within the list element (like below)?

```
<li><img src="voters.jpg"><a href="voters.html">Voters</a></li>
```

Using the *list-style-image* on the *ul* level makes all of the icons the same, and I haven't been able to figure out another way. Most examples I've found teach you how to use images in a list, but only if the bulleted images are the same. I'm definitely open to suggestions and improvements on the way I'm trying to do this.

thanks

```
<div class="content-nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="instructions"><a href="instructions.html">Instructions</a></li>
    <li class="voters"><a href="voters.html">Voters</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

.content-nav {
    font-size:12px;
    width:160px;
    z-index:0;
}

.content-nav ul {
    padding:0 20px;
    margin:30px 0;
}

.content-nav li {
    padding:5px;
    margin:5px 5px;
}

.content-nav li a {
    color:#666;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.content-nav li.voters a {
    background:#FFF;
    color:#666;
    text-decoration:none;
    list-style-image:url(images/voters.jpg);
}

.content-nav li.voters a:hover {
    background:#0CF;
    color:#000;
}

.content-nav li.instructions a {
    background:#FFF;
    color:#666;
    text-decoration:none;
    list-style-image:url(images/voters.jpg);
}

.content-nav li.instructions a:hover {
    background:#0CF;
    color:#000;
}
```

Comment: You're currently applying `list-style-image` to the `a` elements instead of the `li` elements, so that won't work.

Comment: i'm going to adjust the background image instead, but thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could add background images on each list element, and use padding to push the text away from it.

```
<ul>
    <li class="li1">List 1</li>
    <li class="li2">List 2</li>
</ul>

.li1 {
   background:url('li1.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat no-repeat;
   padding-left: 5px;
}
.li2 {
   background:url('li2.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat no-repeat;
   padding-left: 5px;
}
```

Just make sure the padding-left is the same size as the image (or a bit larger if you want spacing)

Answer (score 14):

Using CSS3's `:nth-child()` selector, does not require additional markup on each `<li>` element:

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8qLat9vp/)**

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul li:nth-child(1) {
    list-style-image: url('http://google-maps-icons.googlecode.com/files/teal01.png');
}
ul li:nth-child(2) {
    list-style-image: url('http://google-maps-icons.googlecode.com/files/teal02.png');
}
ul li:nth-child(3) {
    list-style-image: url('http://google-maps-icons.googlecode.com/files/teal03.png');
}
```

**Browser Support:** IE9+, FF3.5+, SA3.1+, OP9.5+, CH2+

Comment: You can use Selectivizr to bring this down to IE6, too. If you also apply `list-style-position:inside;` ([related MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/list-style-position)) to the `ul li`, then the icon shares the space with the text (rather than hovering beside it), which can make positioning easier.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use the icons as background-images for each list element. With this approach you can easily position the "bullet points" also (especially horizontal positioning).

Answer (score 1):

You try to set the `list-style-image` property on an `a` element. Try setting it on the `li` element instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use different icons for each list, than give each list an unique name and use background-image and position it appropriately in CSS.

Comment: By name, I mean class or id as you see appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the image in `content` property of your pseudo-element `::before`:

```
li.item1::before {
    content: url(/Images/icon/item1-icon.svg);
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1em;
    margin-right: 6px;
    margin-left: -1em;
}
```

You obviously need to have a class for each `li` with different image.

Answer (score -1):

```
/* Cờ cho language switcher */
.widget_polylang ul {
    list-style: none;
}
.lang-item-en:before {
    background: url(/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/us.png) no-repeat 0;
    padding-left: 20px;
    content: "";
}
.lang-item-vi:before {
    background: url(/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/vn.png) no-repeat 0;
    padding-left: 20px;
    content: "";
}
```

i code for Polylang's language switcher